# array counter in java not counting correctly

Tags: java, arrays, counter

Using the code below I have a 3x3 array.  Every other check I've designed has been sucessful however counter seems to stop outputting/counting at the 3rd or 4th input I have no idea as to why it would do that.

sorry I left some info out (Thanks tom)

the board is a tic-tac-toe board and there's a method to input the value into the array as listed below

```
 public void inputMove(int inRow, int inCol, String inMove){
    board[inRow][inCol] = inMove;
}
```

---

```
 private boolean checkFill(){
    boolean test = false;
    int counter = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            if(!(board[i][j].equals("-"))){
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(counter);
    return test;

}
```

Comment: Can you add an information how the array `board` is "filled"?

Comment: There is still the content of that array missing. And what do you mean with `3rd` and `4th` input? A `3rd` and `4th` index of the array? (i.e. a `5x5` board) or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided the full code, where board[][] is created. However, I can suggest two things:

1. You are not setting the `test` variable.
2. Verify your board[][] input for 3rd and 4th inputs.

Rest looks good.

Answer (score 0):

Your are using fixed lengths, change it from a fixed `3` to the `.length` property of the `board` array with something like

```
for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) { // board.length instead of 3
    for(int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) { 
        if(!(board[i][j].equals("-"))){
```